# Windows Server 2003: decrease maximum number of concurrent sessions in RDP?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

As you know, Win Server 2003 allows 2 concurrent sessions of **the same user at the same time**
I don't like this, I would like to revert to like it's handled in Windows XP, the connected user will be "kicked out"

It's possible?

Comment: after many months i did not solved this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who cannot find: Start Menu>Administrative Tools>Server Settings    as suggested above: do this.

Go to start: help and support: search "Restrict Each user to one session" and choose the option "Limit users to one remote session : Terminal Services". Then choose the "Using Group Policies (best practice)" heading.

Follow those instructions to limit the number of remote connections for users to a single one (and someone else logging into that account will kick off the person currently using it and take over their session).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually the easiest way is to go to Start Menu>Administrative Tools>Server Settings, within this module you can change the reg key directly labeled "Restrict Each user to one session" and this should do what you want.

Comment: call me dumb, but i cannot find that option...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can actually force already logged on account with this method (since RDP client will just get information from TS that session limit has been exceeded), but you can restrict concurrently logged on accounts with Terminal Service Configuration -tool found from the Administrative Tools.

Open it, go to Connections -folder and open up RDP-Tcp object from the right. Then go to the Network Adapter -tab and change that 2 to 1. Note that console session is not counted in this number.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;237282&x=10&y=10) KB article from ms. Hope this helps.